# File Access Rights - how to replace Windows Msgbox?

Tags: vb.net, windows

I'm denying folder access throuh app, just a temporary thing on one of the forms. Does anybody know how I could replace this Windows Msgbox with my own:

[image]

This Msgbox is produced by Windows when user wants to write data in some folder, while app sets that you can't write at the moment.

Comment: Use the [FOF_NO_UI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759795(v=vs.85).aspx) flag to suppress all message boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you probably can't replace the message box itself, but you could make sure it doesn't show up, and show your own in its place. I'm guessing you're trying to write/change a file? If that's the case, check ahead of time if you have the rights to do so, and if not, show your own messagebox instead of leaving it up to windows to do so.

Comment: thanks for response. I think I cannot do that, problem is that I'm using Webrowser control on my form for looking into these folders, so any action with files in folder are doing in run-time, Windows allways interferce. In this case I should write code that shows my Msgbox when User clicks on delete/cut/copy in Windows right-click context-menu. Which is probably impossible or much harder...

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer as it does not provide an answer to the question

Comment: @QuintinBalsdon Ah, sorry, you're absolutely right.